# Why is the Photos app source code not public?

Tags: pixelsense

Couldn't find a trace of the source code behind the Photos application that runs on MS Surface by default. If anyone has a link to the source code, could you please also let me know? If it's not only can any MSFT moderators please tell me why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a photos application.  It's the user interface to Microsoft Surface.

I guess the point and gesture user interface is no big deal now, with the IPhone and Android.

The user interface to Microsoft Surface is proprietary to Microsoft for the same reason Microsoft Windows 7 is proprietary to Microsoft.  Microsoft created Surface and is free to profit from Surface as much as Microsoft wishes.

Comment: fair point. However, they have released several similar applications with the launch of their SDK SP1.0. This app was not amongst those. 
It's sad to see that instead of providing as much as possible to developers, what's offered are some samples and a rather quite forum...

Comment: It's Microsoft's choice what to release.  It's your choice whether to develop to their API or not.  Honestly, I'd forgotten about Surface.  I think people like the handheld gesture devices better.